# How can I fix my problems with PIL and Pillow in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm using Visual Studio (not VS code) to write Python code. From Solution Explorer and then Python Environments I installed these packages: Pillow, Pillow-PIL, Pil-Lite, PillowImage. I also installed pip the same way. The problem is that when I write this code:

from PIL import Image:

```
   myImage = Image.open("your_image_here");
   myImage.show();
```

I get the message that PIL is unresolved, although that I have all of these packages.

I typed PIL in the solution explorer and there was a field: Run command: pip install PIL. I tried to install it, but I don't get it as a package. After that I uninstalled all other packages and tried to install this one again- the same thing.

I'm trying to run this elementary code since 3 days and there are no results. I tried installing it with CMD, but I'm only getting errors that pip is not recognized, although I used many different paths.

I will be very grateful, if you could help me about this issue.